# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) returns incorrect folder path

Tags: c#, windows, system-tray, appdata

I have created a system tray application. From there I'm trying to get this path:

> "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local"

But instead I'm getting this path:

> "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local"

I'm using this code:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
```

I have tried creating other applications and there it is working but only in system tray it is giving me default user.

Comment: Because you aren't impersonating the logged in user?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you please tell me what is standard way to achieve that.

Comment: You haven't provided much context, I was assuming that you had a background service and were trying to also add a system tray icon.